# Prove that singular homology groups $H_k(M_{diff}, \mathbb{Z})$ and $H_k(M, \mathbb{Z})$ are isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I'm trying to complete the proof from David Mumford's
Algebraic Geometry I, Complex Projective Varieties that the singular
homology groups $H_k(M_{diff}, \mathbb{Z})$ and
$H_k(M, \mathbb{Z})$ for a $C^{\infty}$-manifold $M$ are isomorphic at page 91. About notations:

The singular homology groups are defined as follows: Let
$\Delta^k = $ convex hull in  $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ of unit vectors
$u_i = (0, ..., 1,..., 0) \}$

$\epsilon_i: \Delta^{k-1} \to \Delta^k = $ the linear map talking the
vertices $u_0,..., u_{k-1} $ of $ \Delta^{k-1} $ to the vertices
$u_0,...,\hat{u_i},..., u_{k-1} $ of $ \Delta^{k}$

$C_k(M) = $ group of linear combinations $\sum n_i f_i, n_i \in \mathbb{Z},
f_i$ continuous maps from $\Delta^k$ to $M$.

The *boundary maps* $\partial_k: C_k(M) \to C_{k-1}(M) =$ linear map defined on the generators
$f$ of $C_k(M)$ by

$$ \partial_k f = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i f \circ \epsilon_i $$

And finially $H_k(M, \mathbb{Z}) = Ker(\partial_k) / Im(\partial_{k+1}) $

The differentiable chains considered as subgroup $C_k(M_{diff}) \subset C_k(M)$
are $\mathbb{Z}$-generated by the  $C^{\infty}$ (= analytic) maps
$f: \Delta^k to M$. As before, we can form $Ker(\partial) / Im(\partial)$ on
these smaller chain groups the obtain the map $H_k(M_{diff}, \mathbb{Z}) \to
H_k(M, \mathbb{Z})$ which should be verified to be an isomorphism.

To prove it Mumford suggested to do $5$ steps:

1. introduce a covering $\{U_{\alpha} \}$ such that all intersections
   $U_S = U_{\alpha_1} \cap ... \cap U_{\alpha_k} $ are diffeomorphic to convex
   subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n $
2. Let $C^*(M_{diff}), C^*(M)$ be subcomplexes generated by functions/simplices
   $f$ such that $Im(f) \subset U_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$
3. show that $H_k(C^*(M_{diff}) \simeq H_k(C(M_{diff})$ and
   $H_k(C^*(M) \simeq H_k(C(M)$.
4. Show then that  for all $(\alpha_1, ...,\alpha_k)$,
   $H_k(C(M_{S, diff}) \simeq H_k(C(M_S) =0$ if $k >0$ and $= \mathbb{Z}$ if $k=0$.
5. Show that the qotient complex $C^*(M)/C^*(M_{diff})$ with carriers
   $C^*(M_S)/C^*(M_{S, diff})$ is acyclic by the lemma of acyclic carriers

The lemma which I not want to quote here immediately gives to result, but
I have a lot of problems to show some claims from 3) and 4):

Problems:
Firstly for every $k$ we obviously have canonical inclusions
$C_k^*(M) \subset C_k(M)$ (and the same for diffs). And they are
compatoble with boundary respectively restricted boundary maps, therefore
we obtain moreover an inclusion $C_{\bullet}^*(M) \subset C_{\bullet}(M)$ of
complexes. But I don't see how to show that after passing to homology
groups they become isomorphisms
$H_k(C^*(M) \simeq H_k(C(M)$. It seems that this can be proved by a so called 'subdivision argument' which I wish to discuss [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967540/subdivision-argument-for-group-of-singular-p-chains-g-bredons-sheaf-theory).

Secondly I not know how why we need the exotic assumption that all intersections
$U_S = U_{\alpha_1} \cap ... \cap U_{\alpha_k} $ are diffeomorphic to *convex*
subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n $? With viewpoint to Step 4) in order to
assure that the $U_S$ should have homology groups of a point set: isn't
to require that all intersections $U_S$ are just differomorphic *contractable*.

Thirdly: Why $C^*(M_S)/C^*(M_{S, diff})$ *carries* $C^*(M_S)/C^*(M_{S, diff})$?