# Subdivision argument for group of singular $p$-chains (G. Bredon's Sheaf Theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

I'm thinking about some arguments from Glen Bredon's 'Sheaf Theory' and have a lot of problems with understanding how they work. The first question deals with explanations from page 26:

We denote by $X$ the topological space, and $\mathcal{A}$ a locally
constant sheaf on $X$.
For $U \subset X$. Let $S^p(U;\mathcal{A})$ be the group of singular
$p$-chains of $U$ with values in $\mathcal{A}$. That is, an element
$f \in S^p(U;\mathcal{A})$ is a
function that assigns to each singular $p$-simplex
$\sigma: \Delta_p \to U $  of $U$, a cross
section $f(\sigma) \in \Gamma(\sigma^*(\mathcal{A}))$, where $\Delta_p$
denotes the standard $p$-simplex.

Let $\mathcal{U} := \{U_{\alpha} \}$ be a covering of $X$ by open
sets, and let $S^p(\mathcal{U};\mathcal{A})$ be the group of singular
cochains based on ll-small singular simplices. Then Bredon uses an argument I do not understand. He says

> 'Then a subdivision argument shows that the surjection

$$j_{\mathcal{U}}: S^*(U;\mathcal{A}) \to S^*(\mathcal{U};\mathcal{A})$$

> induces a cohomology isomorphism.'

Question #1: what is this 'subdivision argument' and why does it
imply that $j_{\mathcal{U}}$ induces an isomorphism on cohomology?

Question #2: On page 180, Bredon remarks moreover another important
property of the group of singular
$p$-chains and their associated sheaf: assume that $L$ is a principal ideal domain,
which will be taken as the base ring. Let $\mathcal{A}:= L$ be the
locally constant sheaf with values in $L$ and let
$\mathfrak{S}^* = \mathfrak{S}^*(X; L) $ the sheafification of presheaf
$ U \to S^*(U;\mathcal{A})$. Therefore the sheaf $\mathfrak{S}^*$ can be
naturally considered as $L$-module.

Bredon claims in the middle of page 180 that the stalks of $\mathfrak{S}^*$
are torsion-free. Why is that true?

Since the stalks of the sheaf $\mathfrak{S}^p(X; L)$ and the presheaf
associating $ U \to S^p(U;L)$ are equal, it is sufficient to think
about the direct limit of the $S^p(U; L)$, where the $U$ form an open system of neighborhoods around $x \in X$.

For sufficiently small open neighbourhood $x \in U \subset X$, the  $S^p(U; L)$ is a free $L$-module, so torsion free. It's direct limit, which is by definition the stalk at $x \in X$  is in general not free. Is it nevertheless torsion free?

Comment: Such a subdivision argument is well explained in Vick's book **Homology Theory**. The idea is that you can define a subdivision operator that replaces a simplex by in R^n by the sum of simplices of the barycentric subdivision. Iterations of this operator produces a subdivision whose simplices are arbitrarily small. When given a simplex $\sigma:\Delta^n\to X$ you will subdivide the source until the simplices thus obtained have the property that $\sigma$ maps them into open sets in $\mathcal U$. Then there is a chain homotopy argument to tell you that this operator is homotopic to the identity.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Yes thank you,  I found it. Although I basically understand the argument there that
there exist a chain homotopy $H: C_n \to C_{n+1}$ between the
subdivision operator $S$ and identity forcing them to have same
homotopy, I not understand what is geometrically going on in $H$.
In contrast the idea how acts $S$ has a clear geometric meaning,
while $H$ stays obscure to me from viewpoint of geometric intuition.
Do you know how one can imagine $H$ geometrically?