# Direct Limit of Torsion-free modules is Torsion-free

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

We denote by $X$ the topological space and by $L$ a commutative ring with one.
Let $S: U \mapsto S(U)$ a presheaf on $X$ in $L$-modules, i.e.
for every open $U \subset X$ the $S(U)$ is a $L$-module.
Assume that for every open subset $U$ the $L$-modules
$S(U)$ are *torsion-free*.

For a $x \in X$ the stalk of $S$ at $x$ is defined as the
direct limit of the $S(V_x)$ where $\{V_x\}$ are open subsets of $X$
containing $x$.

The question is if the stalk $S_x$ is also torsion free if the ring
$L$ is principal ideal domain or more general just arbitrary.
The question is related to  [secound question from this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967540/subdivision-argument-for-group-of-singular-p-chains-g-bredons-sheaf-theory).

Comment: Yes. You can prove this explicitly. Have you tried?

Comment: @Thorgott: What I tried: By def every $s \in S_x$ have a representant 
$t \in S(V)$ for appropriate open $V$ under canonical map
$f_V: S(V) \to S_x$. We assumed that $s \neq 0$ and $(V)$
is torsion free, thus $l \cdot t \neq 0$ for every $0 \neq l \in L$.
The map $f_V$ is a $L$-module morphism so, $l \cdot f_V(t) 
=f_V(l \cdot t)$. But here I see a problem. In general 
$f_V(l \cdot t)$ is not injective, so it could happen that $f_V(l \cdot t)
=0$. That's my problem.

Comment: But keep in mind how the stalk is defined. What does it mean, by definition, when $f_V(lt)=0$?

Comment: that there exist a open $V' \subset V$ where $lt =0$ restricted to $S(V')$? Ok, and how does it help me?

Comment: $S(V^{\prime})$ is torsion-free, by assumption.

Comment: I see, then pulling $l$ out of $s_{V'}(l \cdot t)$ 
applying $L$-module structure gives a conradiction! +1